# Create absolute paths in tar

Tags: command-line, tar

How do I rewrite file paths to be absolute in tar, other than rewriting the actual tar file? e.g.

```
$ tree tmp_fs
tmp_fs
├── bin
├── boot
│   └── kernel
├── include
├── lib
└── share
    └── misc
        └── logo

6 directories, 2 files

$ tar cC tmp_fs . | tar t
./
./share/
./share/misc/
./share/misc/logo
./lib/
./boot/
./boot/kernel
./include/
./bin
```

Ideally, I'd like to find an option to pass to tar that'd make the paths all be absolute (i.e. `/boot/kernel` instead of `./boot/kernel`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean when you're extracting the files, you just extract the tar file to `/`

For example:

```
tar -C / -xvf myfile.tar
```

If you're trying to force the tarfile to extract to a specific location, no matter what the person extracting it specifies, you can't do that. You'd need to include it in some kind of package, such as a `.deb` or `.rpm` file.

Comment: I know this is at least *possible*, because there are dozens of Google search results on people trying to do the opposite (eg. have `./whatever.txt` instead of `/home/me/Desktop/whatever.txt`). The TAR format supports it, too (because I can do this with a hex editor), I'm just trying to do it without needing a hex editor or a post-processing step with Python/Perl/whatever language of choice.

Comment: You can use the -P option to get the absolute path, however it doesn't extract the file absolutely. You can't get it to do that. Just try it with your hex edited file, it will still extract to whatever directory you specify.

Comment: The -P option makes the paths `/home/me/Desktop/whatever.txt`; if I just want `/whatever.txt`, is there a way?

Comment: Weirdly, there is. You can use something like: `--transform='s_.*/_/_g'` The `--transform` expression is a sed substitution expression. This one replaces /anything/like/this/thing/ with just /